# How to remove Indian tea stains over cotton vest

Tags: home

I am looking for simple Indian Tea stain remove from my vest(s). These are of cotton and the brownish stain looks very odd. Is there any home remedy to remove them. I found difficult to get even chemicals. So home available items that can remove the stain will be helpful.

Comment: It can be helpful if you'll attach an image

Comment: common baking soda might work.

Answer (score 1):

Once a stain is on material, then washed, it is usually set. It is always preferable to treat the stain immediately; preferably, before washing the garment.

Tea is an extremely difficult stain. Are there other colors on the vest or is it solid white?

Either way, I would start with soaking the vest in a solution of warm water and [Super Washing Soda](https://www.armandhammer.com/laundry/additives/additives/super-washing-soda-detergent-booster). I'd also put a small amount of vinegar in there as well. Soak for around 15 minutes, when wash on gentle. Note the stain. If it is not out, then I would repeat again.